# Using Japanese with my child

Tags: spoken-language, kinship-terms

I have been learning/using Japanese for the past 16 years and now that I have become a mother to my 3 month old son, I would like to bring him up exposed to both English and Japanese. I haven't had many interactions with small children so don't know much baby/child specific language. I would love some suggestions. E.g. Can you use 愛している to say I love you to your child, or is that only for use with a significant other?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet, [recommended reading](https://www.amazon.com/Raising-Bilingual-Child-Living-Language/dp/1400023343).

Comment: 愛して(い)る more often used for couples (or spouses) rather than parent-to-child relationship. 大好き is considered more appropriate for relationship between family members.

Answer (score 1):

(your son's name)-ちゃんが、だいすきよ！

Or just だ～いすき！